# Discord.py Buttons Error unexpected keyword

Tags: discord, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "Discord Buttons!",
        components=[
            [Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Red"),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.red, label="Red", disabled=True),
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.URL, label="Youtube", url="https://youtube.com")],
             Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Blue", emoji=""),
        ],
    )
    res = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
    if res.channel == ctx.message.channel:
        await res.repond(
            type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
            content=f"Pressed!"
        )
```

And here is the error it keeps on giving:

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'components'
```

I am trying to make a command where if you say $test, it responds with Buttons: https://support.discord.com/hc/article_attachments/1500019725621/buttons.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to use [discord-components](https://pypi.org/project/discord-components/). For this, you will need to install the package with `pip install discord-components` and then add the following to your code if you haven't done so.

```py
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button

bot = Bot('$') # Prefix

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(bot)
    # ...

# ...
```

Then from there you should be able to add a `components` field to send with `Button`s in it.

Comment: Could you edit the post to show your full code (or a more minimal example that does the same thing)?